# Missing Human Icon Style after upgrading LibreOffice

Tags: icons, libreoffice

I’m running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After upgrading LibreOffice to version 5.3 I’m missing Human Icon Style in **Tools -> Options -> View -> Icon Style**. Package *libreoffice-style-human* is installed and it is already the newest version, but it doesn't appear in **Options**.

I think I have read somewhere that this package isn't maintained well any more. Anybody knows if this will change in the future?

Or is it any way to get this style back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Human icon theme for LibreOffice has been removed in 5.3 release, which is noted under ["Feature removal" in the release note](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.3#Feature_removal_.2F_deprecation). The rationale is found in [this commit description](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/commit/?id=d1f4b84fa) as quoted below.

> **Drop 'Human' icon theme**
>
> Was used in Ubuntu formerly, but they now switched to breeze.
>
> Human is mostly similiar to Tango, with some Ubuntu colors.
>
> So it should be enough to keep Tango.

There are two workarounds to get back the similar style:

1. Install **Tango symbol style** for LibreOffice (`libreoffice-style-tango`). This is available for all releases of LibreOffice.
2. Install **Human symbol style** for LibreOffice (`libreoffice-style-human`). This is available for LibreOffice 5.2 and older releases only. Requires downgrade, at least to LibreOffice 5.2 via [PPA of 5.2.x series stable backports](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-5-2) or [DEB package of LibreOffice Still](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-still/).

Tango is claimed to be "a good fallback, its high quality, consistent" icon set, when [icons in Ubuntu Dapper were being worked](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DapperUbuntuIcons) back then. That claim remained true to this date.

LibreOffice 5.3 has better user experience in some sense and it is not worth to downgrade for using the unmaintained icon theme. Therefore, using Tango symbol style is the easiest workaround for being the closest alternative to Human symbol style.